# Place an image infront of the map

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, dictionary

could someone please guide me in the steps involved in creating something similar to this:

http://bikepathcountry.com/plan/

Currently I have my map setup and all my markers being called onto the map from an SQL db, I have the image/form designed but I struggle to place it infront of my map as shown in the link above, I'm not worried about making it work just yet, im just trying to get it to display over the map, how can I do this? :)

Thanks for the help! I've a relative beginner with this stuff, apologies if this is such an easy trivial issue :D

I can make my image above or below the map, but I would really like to have it shown infront of the map like the link I posted.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more context - What language are you trying to do this in? Do you have some example code we can look at (so we can possibly just suggest a 1-line change)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your question is about the blue signs with the bikes in them they are referred to as markers and you create them like this

```
 var image = new     google.maps.MarkerImage('http://mymarkerlocation.com/markers/somemarker.png');
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: image,

});
```

If however your question is about the top left panel with text and graphics well that's just a div placed on top of the map.

Comment: worked a treat thanks, got my search box displayed ontop. now to sort out my markers :)